# OS X El Capitan, ProFTPD, Login incorrect!

Tags: macos

I can not login to ProFTPD server. The logfile says:

```
Jul 26 09:10:08 macbook proftpd: XX.XX.XXX.XXX:51408: PASS (hidden)[3941]: in openpam_load_module(): no pam_opendirectory.so found
Jul 26 09:10:08 macbook proftpd[3941]: 192.168.0.101 (XX.XX.XXX.XXX[XX.XX.XXX.XXX]) - USER ftp1 (Login failed): Incorrect password.
```

/private/etc/pam.d/ftpd:

```
# login: auth account password session
auth       required       pam_opendirectory.so
account    required       pam_permit.so
password   required       pam_deny.so
session    required       pam_permit.so
```

System: OS 10.11.6

Comment: I believe you are referencing the modules for the ftpd daemon that ships with OS X and not the proftpd daemon.  Those should be in whatever directory proftpd was installed to (i.e. /../../proftpd/modules)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! Unfortunately i am not experienced enough to completely understand it. I installed ProFTPD as part of XAMPP. There is a directory /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/proftpd which does not(!) contain a directory "modules". There is a directory /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/modules which contains a lot of files named like "mod_foo_bar.so" (nothing like "pam_..."). Do i have to reference to some of those in /private/etc/pam.d/ftpd ? If yes - which ones?

Comment: I haven't used ProFTPD server in many, many, years and that was on Solaris and Linux boxes, not OSX.  I use SCP and SFTP now (SSH protocol).  But if memory serves, you need to have the pam_opendirectory.so in the modules directory of XAMPP, not /etc/pam/ftpd as ftpd is the built in ftp daemon, not proFTPD

Comment: Thanks again for your support!!! I tried 2 symlinks "pam_opendirectory.so -> /usr/lib/pam/pam_opendirectory.so.2" in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/modules and /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/proftpd - but the server still logs "no pam_opendirectory.so found".

Comment: Unfortunately my plan was somehow a bad idea in the first place! Installing XAMPP on OSX El Capitan was absolutely unnecessary for my purposes. Apache2 is shiped with EL Capitan (i updated from PHP 5 to PHP 7), installing MySQL was easy and i use the native FTP daemon of EL Capitan. Only thing tricky about the latter : standard users are disabled from FTP by default. They can be enabled by adding them to the system group com.apple.access_ftp